# Strange warning when trying to extend class

Tags: php, abstraction, zend-studio, simplepie

I started getting strange warnings, after extending a class that extends another
`Event_Feed_Item > My_Feed_Item > SimplePie_Item`

```
- Cannot extend from interface 
 'SimplePie_Item'
- Implementors of methods in 
 'SimplePie_Item'
```

However on runtime it works fine. Also SimplePie_Item is not an interface, it's a simple Class..
Just need to know if I'm running into trouble, or if i can just ignore this warning

**EDIT** I'm extending [this class](https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie/blob/master/SimplePie/Item.php)
Also this is the skeleton from my classes

```
class My_Feed_Item extends SimplePie_Item // error is triggered here
{
    protected $_source_id = null;

    public function set_source ($source_id)
    {
    }
    public function get_image ()
    {
    }
    public function get_venue_id ()
    {
    }
    public function get_venue_nm ()
    {
    }
    public function cleanString($str)
    {
    }
}

class Event_Feed_Item extends My_Feed_Item
{
    public function get_event_nm ()
    {

    }
    public function get_event_start_dt ()
    {

    }
    public function get_event_end_dt ()
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: Make sure that any overridden methods use the same definition and that all abstract/interface methods are defined

Comment: where are you seeing those errors?

Comment: Actually I see these errors in Zend Studio. Not really affecting the live site so I just chose to ignore it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same issue.  Make sure the Build Path and/or Include Path for the project in Zend Studio have the path to the directory where the parent class is located.  In PHP Explorer, right-click the project and choose Build Path -> Configure Build Path.  Or right-click the project and choose Include Path -> Configure Include Path.